# While loop over a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists as shown below. I want to iterate the list and for each list item with 'yes' at index 1, I want to update index 4 with count of occurrences of 'no' before I get another yes and then add add 1 to it.  My solution works except the 2nd to last item (435...) should have 2, but I'm getting 0.

Input data:

```
[[428, 'yes', 428, 0, 0],
 [429, 'yes', 429, 0, 0],
 [430, 'no', 430, 0, 0],
 [431, 'no', 431, 0, 0],
 [432, 'yes', 432, 0, 0],
 [433, 'yes', 433, 0, 0],
 [434, 'no', 434, 0, 0],
 [435, 'yes', 435, 0, 0],
 [436, 'no', 436, 0, 0]]
```

Desired Output:

```
[[428, 'yes', 428, 0, 1],
 [429, 'yes', 429, 0, 3],
 [430, 'no', 430, 0, 0],
 [431, 'no', 431, 0, 0],
 [432, 'yes', 432, 0, 1],
 [433, 'yes', 433, 0, 2],
 [434, 'no', 434, 0, 0],
 [435, 'yes', 435, 0, 2],
 [436, 'no', 436, 0, 0]]
```

Here is my entire script I'm using to test

```
fullchart = [
[428, 'yes', 428, 0, 0],
[429, 'yes', 429, 0, 0],
[430, 'no', 430, 0, 0],
[431, 'no', 431, 0, 0],
[432, 'yes', 432, 0, 0],
[433, 'yes', 433, 0, 0],
[434, 'no', 434, 0, 0],
[435, 'yes', 435, 0, 0],
[436, 'no', 436, 0, 0]
]

print('fullchart 1')
pprint.pprint(fullchart)

end_page = 0
for i in range(len(fullchart)):
    if fullchart[i][1] == 'yes':
        for b in range(i+1, len(fullchart)):
            print('printing b')
            print(b)
            if fullchart[b][1] == 'no':
                end_page += 1
            else:
                fullchart[i][4] = end_page + 1
                break
    else:
        pass

print('fullchart 2')
pprint.pprint(fullchart)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Also, what does your title have to do with it? There are no `while` loops here...

Comment: in my output, I am not getting a 2 at the index 4 position like this [435, 'yes', 435, 0, 2]

Comment: @ShadowRanger I feel like it might need to be a while loop

Comment: @MarkMeyer, that was a fat finger, sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the easiest way to deal with this is to iterate backwards over the list:

```
l = [
    [428, 'yes', 428, 0, 0],
    [429, 'yes', 429, 0, 0],
    [430, 'no', 430, 0, 0],
    [431, 'no', 431, 0, 0],
    [432, 'yes', 432, 0, 0],
    [433, 'yes', 433, 0, 0],
    [434, 'no', 434, 0, 0],
    [435, 'yes', 435, 0, 0],
    [436, 'no', 436, 0, 0]
]

count = 1

for row in reversed(l):
    if row[1] == 'no':
        count += 1
    else:
        row[4] = count
        count = 1
```

Making `l`:

```
[[428, 'yes', 428, 0, 1],
 [429, 'yes', 429, 0, 3],
 [430, 'no', 430, 0, 0],
 [431, 'no', 431, 0, 0],
 [432, 'yes', 432, 0, 1],
 [433, 'yes', 433, 0, 2],
 [434, 'no', 434, 0, 0],
 [435, 'yes', 435, 0, 2],
 [436, 'no', 436, 0, 0]]
```

That should be considerably more efficient too since it only looks at each item once.

Answer (score 0):

The logic error is here:

```
        if fullchart[b][1] == 'no':
            end_page += 1
        else:
            fullchart[i][4] = end_page + 1
            break
```

Note that you update your `yes`-row entry only when you hit an answer that is not `no`.  Since there is no such element after the final `yes`, that last desired update doesn't happen.
You need to repeat that update after the end of the loop.

Also, I think you'll find this much easier to debug if you change the approach.  Count consecutive `no` answers until you hit something else.  At *that* point, back up to the previous `yes` row -- which you can find easily with that count -- and update its 4th element.
Do it one last time after the loop.